# TailwindUI transitions & transforms

Tags: css-animations, css-transitions, tailwind-css, stenciljs, tsx

I'm using TailwindCSS, TailwindUI and StencilJS to build a dropdown TailwindUI component, but i'm having difficulty figuring out how to apply the suggested transitions provided next to the tailwind UI component.

Here is the tailwindUI component:

```html
<div class="relative inline-block text-left">
  <div>
    <span class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
      <button type="button" class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition ease-in-out duration-150" id="options-menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Options
        <svg class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <!--
    Dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.

    Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
      From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
      To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
      From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
      To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
  -->
  <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg">
    <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="options-menu">
      <div class="py-1">
        <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
          <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M17.414 2.586a2 2 0 00-2.828 0L7 10.172V13h2.828l7.586-7.586a2 2 0 000-2.828z"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h4a1 1 0 010 2H4v10h10v-4a1 1 0 112 0v4a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
          </svg>
          Edit
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
          <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M7 9a2 2 0 012-2h6a2 2 0 012 2v6a2 2 0 01-2 2H9a2 2 0 01-2-2V9z"/>
            <path d="M5 3a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2V5h8a2 2 0 00-2-2H5z"/>
          </svg>
          Duplicate
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>
      <div class="py-1">
        <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
          <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M4 3a2 2 0 100 4h12a2 2 0 100-4H4z"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 8h14v7a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V8zm5 3a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 110 2H9a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
          </svg>
          Archive
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
          <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-8.707l-3-3a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414L10.586 9H7a1 1 0 100 2h3.586l-1.293 1.293a1 1 0 101.414 1.414l3-3a1 1 0 000-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
          </svg>
          Move
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>
      <div class="py-1">
        <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
          <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M8 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6zM8 11a6 6 0 016 6H2a6 6 0 016-6zM16 7a1 1 0 10-2 0v1h-1a1 1 0 100 2h1v1a1 1 0 102 0v-1h1a1 1 0 100-2h-1V7z"/>
          </svg>
          Share
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
          <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.172 5.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L10 6.343l1.172-1.171a4 4 0 115.656 5.656L10 17.657l-6.828-6.829a4 4 0 010-5.656z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
          </svg>
          Add to favorites
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>
      <div class="py-1">
        <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
          <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9 2a1 1 0 00-.894.553L7.382 4H4a1 1 0 000 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h8a2 2 0 002-2V6a1 1 0 100-2h-3.382l-.724-1.447A1 1 0 0011 2H9zM7 8a1 1 0 012 0v6a1 1 0 11-2 0V8zm5-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v6a1 1 0 102 0V8a1 1 0 00-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
          </svg>
          Delete
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my attempt to create that same component (and animation) in a StencilJS tsx class and css file:

```js
import { Component, h, State } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'animate-ex',
  styleUrl: 'animate-ex.css'
})
export class AnimateEx {
    
    @State() isOpen = false;
   
    setIsOpen(isOpen: boolean): void {
        this.isOpen = isOpen;
    }

    render() {
       
        return (
            <div id="tw-dropdown" class=" ml-1/3 mt-5 relative inline-block text-left">
                <div>
                    <span class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.setIsOpen(!this.isOpen)} class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition ease-in-out duration-150" id="options-menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            Options
                            <svg class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div id='TRANSITION_HERE' class={(this.isOpen?'show transition ease-out duration-100 transform opacity-100 scale-100 ':'hide transition ease-in duration-75 transform opacity-0 scale-95 ')+'drop-down-content origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg'}>
                    <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="options-menu">
                        <div class="py-1">
                            <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
                                <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path d="M17.414 2.586a2 2 0 00-2.828 0L7 10.172V13h2.828l7.586-7.586a2 2 0 000-2.828z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h4a1 1 0 010 2H4v10h10v-4a1 1 0 112 0v4a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                </svg>
                                Edit
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
                                <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path d="M7 9a2 2 0 012-2h6a2 2 0 012 2v6a2 2 0 01-2 2H9a2 2 0 01-2-2V9z"/>
                                    <path d="M5 3a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2V5h8a2 2 0 00-2-2H5z"/>
                                </svg>
                                Duplicate
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>
                        <div class="py-1">
                            <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
                                <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path d="M4 3a2 2 0 100 4h12a2 2 0 100-4H4z"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 8h14v7a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V8zm5 3a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 110 2H9a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                </svg>
                                Archive
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
                                <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-8.707l-3-3a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414L10.586 9H7a1 1 0 100 2h3.586l-1.293 1.293a1 1 0 101.414 1.414l3-3a1 1 0 000-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                </svg>
                                Move
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>
                        <div class="py-1">
                            <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
                                <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path d="M8 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6zM8 11a6 6 0 016 6H2a6 6 0 016-6zM16 7a1 1 0 10-2 0v1h-1a1 1 0 100 2h1v1a1 1 0 102 0v-1h1a1 1 0 100-2h-1V7z"/>
                                </svg>
                                Share
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
                                <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.172 5.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L10 6.343l1.172-1.171a4 4 0 115.656 5.656L10 17.657l-6.828-6.829a4 4 0 010-5.656z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                </svg>
                                Add to favorites
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>
                        <div class="py-1">
                            <a href="#" class="group flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
                                <svg class="mr-3 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 group-focus:text-gray-500" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9 2a1 1 0 00-.894.553L7.382 4H4a1 1 0 000 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h8a2 2 0 002-2V6a1 1 0 100-2h-3.382l-.724-1.447A1 1 0 0011 2H9zM7 8a1 1 0 012 0v6a1 1 0 11-2 0V8zm5-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v6a1 1 0 102 0V8a1 1 0 00-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                </svg>
                                Delete
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
  }

}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

The `div` with `id`=**TRANSITION_HERE** is where, I think, the transition goes, but I can't determine what is meant by *entering*/*leaving* here, and the only references I can find are for Vue and React frameworks, which I'm not using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon a package called 'el-transition' - it worked like a charm and really nicely works with the way tailwindUI expresses animations (similar to alpine.js from what I understand).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/el-transition

- Use the following properties to set the animations:

```
data-transtion-enter: Applied during the entire entering phase.
data-transition-enter-start: Added before element is inserted, removed one frame after element is inserted.
data-transition-enter-end: Added one frame after element is inserted (at the same time enter-start is removed), removed when transition/animation finishes.
data-transition-leave: Applied during the entire leaving phase.
data-transition-leave-start: Added immediately when a leaving transition is triggered, removed after one frame.
data-transition-leave-end: Added one frame after a leaving transition is triggered (at the same time leave-start is removed), removed when the transition/animation finishes.
```

- Save the elements with the properties using `ref={(elRef)=>this.elRef=elRef}`
- Call `enter()` or `leave()` on each of the ref(s) saved that require transition

I ended up using this library for a different component but if it's helpful I change the original answer's code and post the component I did use this for.